# Save ActiveRecord object without commit rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

while I was investigating my mysql performance on my rails project, i noticed half of my querys are based on commit. IS there any way to create without commit ?

[image: source of the problem]

Thanks

ruby 2.1.2
rails 4.1.4

Comment: The actions `insert`, `update`, `delete` and `replace` are each wrapped in a `commit` by Rails. This being said, most of your `commit` SQL actions probably are `insert`, `update` and stuff like that (to be confirmed!)

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking or what you are trying to do. To save something to the database requires a commit at some point, one way or another.

Comment: Probably he wants a trasaction and execute commit after updates, inserts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on your question, but have you tried using 'rails c' from the command line? You could get into the console to add a record to your database. For example:

user = User.new(username: "johndoe", first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe")

- '.new' creates but does not save to the database
- user.save will then in turn commit record to database
- '.create' creates and saves the record to the database